# How to Turn ON the Volume through cron using shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, cron

I tried this command

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 100%+ on
```

directly in terminal, and it works, also if I save the command in a file `sound.sh` and run `./sound.sh` it works.

If I run the same file through crontab, it runs (the log file is showing it), but it does not turn on the volume.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu.  Could you give more details on how you added your shell to cron?  The line you added in the crontab is a good start.

Comment: I show the my crontab command line in double quotes "*/5 * * * * /opt/backup/sound.sh" , It tells at every five minutes run this sound.sh file.

Comment: I would add some echo command before and after the call to amixer, to make sure.

Comment: Actually This command "amixer -D pulse sset Master unmute" unmute the volume through directly running in terminal, if it is run through crontab, actually its running this is shown in log file, but not enable the sound. Is there any idea for this? my shell script is look like #!/bin/sh

SCRIPT=`realpath -s $0`
SCRIPTPATH=`dirname $SCRIPT`
amixer -D pulse sset Master unmute